# Can't login to website after installing wildcard certificate IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a SAAS application that works fine using http but I just created and installed a wildcard certificate and added the https to the iis binding.

The certificate install completed successfully and verifies fine.  I am able to view the certificate from iis binding and from the server certificate selection in IIS.

The problem is I can login to the application using http but I cannot login to the application when I use https.  I am using the same username and password for both http and https connections.

I cannot find any errors in the logs and am at a loss.  I am thinking about requesting another certificate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Describe what is "cannot log in". If it is a login page of your application, you have to check the code.

Comment: Hi,
The code works just fine on my test and production servers using https.

Comment: you can enable HTTPS in your test machine, and I think it would break too.

Comment: I already have https enabled in test and production and they work fine.
This is only happening on our staging server.  This is a new cert

Comment: would you mind use Fiddler to dig into the request/response sequence. No other info can be more useful than that.